# OnCreate runs AFTER onActivityResult on Honeycomb?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am using `startActivityForResult()` to allow the user to choose a file form the file system in my app. After the file is chosen, `OnActivityResult()` runs and I save the file path to a variable and proceed. This works fine on Android 2.3 and lower.

On Honeycomb, however, `OnCreate()` runs again AFTER `OnActivityReult()`, essentially restarting my activity so I am unable to hold any variables because it runs an entirely new activity after I get the result.

Any idea why this is, and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One potential cause is in case the the device is low on memory, your activity was killed to claim system resources.

> What can I do about it?

Save your variables in `onSaveInstanceState` method.

In the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) documentation they give an exact case which might be yours, read about it (In the `onSaveInstanceState` method documentation).